# Hopeless = terrible?

Tags: vocabulary

I saw a sentence about the use of "hopeless". Here's the sentence:

> I'm hopeless at telling jokes.

When I see "hopeless", the one thing that appears in my mind is something that makes I lose hope. So, in this sentence, does it mean the same as terrible or I lose my hope to tell jokes? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes & No, It depends on your definition of terrible. If you mean it in the sense of not being good at something then Yes, your example means terrible. However in the case of "loose hope", Hopeless is not the same as terrible .

terrible adjective (BAD AT)

Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/terrible)

very bad at doing something:

---

There are two meanings of hopeless,

as you have correctly pointed ***"without hope"***. The other use is ***"without skill"***. In the case of telling Jokes it will be without skill. If you are without skill at doing something, then you could be terrible at doing it.

**hopeless; adjective**

**without hope:**
a hopeless situation
They searched for survivors but it was hopeless.
She was depressed and felt totally hopeless about the future.

**completely without skill** at a particular activity:
I'm hopeless at sports.
He's a hopeless cook.

Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hopeless?q=Hopeless)